# JSX - load an image

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I'm playing with reactjs and am trying to change the image on click. There seems to be a problem with finding the images.

The piece of code is:

```
render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'holes' : 'emilia';
    return (
      <div className={text} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h1>You like {text}. Click to toggle</h1>
        <img src="images/{text}.jpg" />

      </div>

    );
  }
```

If you hard-code, the images are accessible "images/emilia.jpg" or "images/holes.jpg". The onclick event works fine as the `<h1>` element correctly toggles between 'holes' and 'emilia'.

How can a part of the path to img be a variable as in the above example?

Comment: `src={"images" + text + ".jpg"}`

Answer (score 1):

As you're writing this using ES6, one way to do what you're asking would be to use string literals.

```
<img src={`images/${text}.jpg`} />
```

You could also use string concatenation, but I think the above method is the most readable, and follows closely with what you've already written.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
src={"images/" + text + ".jpg"}
```

or if you use ES6 you can just type

```
src={`images/${text}.jpg`}
```